# Stuck on 42066 Air Race Jet model B

Tags: technic, building

I've successfully built model A of the [Air Race Jet](https://brickset.com/sets/42066-1/Air-Race-Jet) but with model B I've got stuck on page 7, instruction 8. How do you do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Nice job finishing Model "A"!

As for Model "B", known as "Private Jet", follow *[this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_80sVRWghc)* and head on over to *Youtuber THINK LOUDER's* speed build of this model.

[image]

- First, Mute the video.
- Second, Pause the video.
- Third, Open the setting for video playback, which is the "Gear" icon
  in the bottom right hand corner of the video, to slow down the speed to "0.25".
- Forth, Play the video and skip to minute 1:47 into the video.
- Fifth, and finally, Watch how this guy builds up until minute 2:04 into the video, which is where you are stuck, page 7, instruction 8.

[image]

Good luck! You can do it Bro!